# Scipy.optimize.minimize only iterates some variables.

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I have written python (2.7.3) code wherein I aim to create a weighted sum of 16 data sets, and compare the result to some expected value. My problem is to find the weighting coefficients which will produce the best fit to the model. To do this, I have been experimenting with scipy's optimize.minimize routines, but have had mixed results.

Each of my individual data sets is stored as a 15x15 ndarray, so their weighted sum is also a 15x15 array. I define my own 'model' of what the sum should look like (also a 15x15 array), and quantify the goodness of fit between my result and the model using a basic least squares calculation.

```
R=np.sum(np.abs(model/np.max(model)-myresult)**2)
```

'myresult' is produced as a function of some set of parameters 'wts'. I want to find the set of parameters 'wts' which will minimise R.

To do so, I have been trying this:

```
res = minimize(get_best_weightings,wts,bounds=bnds,method='SLSQP',options={'disp':True,'eps':100})
```

Where my objective function is:

```
def get_best_weightings(wts):


wts_tr=wts[0:16]
wts_ti=wts[16:32]

for i,j in enumerate(portlist):

    originalwtsr[j]=wts_tr[i]
    originalwtsi[j]=wts_ti[i]

realwts=originalwtsr
imagwts=originalwtsi

myresult=make_weighted_beam(realwts,imagwts,1)

R=np.sum((np.abs(modelbeam/np.max(modelbeam)-myresult))**2)

return R
```

The input (wts) is an ndarray of shape (32,), and the output, R, is just some scalar, which should get smaller as my fit gets better. By my understanding, this is exactly the sort of problem ("Minimization of scalar function of one or more variables.") which scipy.optimize.minimize is designed to optimize (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html ).

However, when I run the code, although the optimization routine seems to iterate over different values of all the elements of wts, only a few of them seem to 'stick'. Ie, all but four of the values are returned with the same values as my initial guess. To illustrate, I plot the values of my initial guess for wts (in blue), and the optimized values in red. You can see that for most elements, the two lines overlap. 
Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYMuS.jpg

Changing just these few parameters is not enough to get a good answer, and I can't understand why the other parameters aren't also being optimised. I suspect that maybe I'm not understanding the nature of my minimization problem, so I'm hoping someone here can point out where I'm going wrong.

I have experimented with a variety of minimize's inbuilt methods (I am by no means committed to SLSQP, or certain that it's the most appropriate choice), and with a variety of 'step sizes' eps. The bounds I am using for my parameters are all (-4000,4000). I only have scipy version .11, so I haven't tested a basinhopping routine to get the global minimum (this needs .12). I have looked at minimize.brute, but haven't tried implementing it yet - thought I'd check if anyone can steer me in a better direction first.

Any advice appreciated! Sorry for the wall of text and the possibly (probably?) idiotic question. I can post more of my code if necessary, but it's pretty long and unpolished.

Comment: A possible explanation is that your objective function is very flat in those parameters, for example because of bad scaling of variables, or due to a coding mistake in the objective function that for example makes it independent of those parameters. It's not really possible to say much more here without knowing what the objective function is. As a first step, you could check that the value of the objective function actually depends on every parameter.